# config.h: No such file or directory after importing eclipse ndk project in android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I have a working project in eclipse that uses ffmpeg. The implementation is like in this tutorial: http://enoent.fr/blog/2014/06/20/compile-ffmpeg-for-android/

After importing the project into Android Studio 2.1 the only error I got was related to

`android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` in my gradle.properties

When I try to run the project I get the following error:

```
 config.h: No such file or directory
```

on ffmpeg.h

```
#ifndef FFMPEG_H
#define FFMPEG_H

#include "config.h"

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
....
```

My build.gradle has:

```
ndk {
            moduleName "videokit"
        }
```

What should I do to fix the problem?

**LE: Possible solution:**
- I created the jniLibs folder and added the .so file from eclipse lib's folder and it seem to work...

Comment: try run ./configure again

Comment: @V-master I don't see any configure file

Comment: In the tutorial you referenced, there is a section with configure: http://enoent.fr/blog/2014/06/20/compile-ffmpeg-for-android/#Configuration try rerun this part

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think that helps, as the Eclipse project works fine, the only issue is when importing the project in Android Studio